# how to fill the color of a sphere with \addplot3

Tags: pgfplots, color

I need to fill a sphere with one color. I've read the documentation and there is `fill=blue` but in my case is not working. The below picture shows what I've got so far.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        width=0.8\textwidth,
        axis equal,
        axis lines = center,
        x label style={at={(axis cs:0,2,0)},anchor=south},
        y label style={at={(axis cs:0,2,0)},anchor=west},
        z label style={at={(axis cs:-1,2,.1)},anchor=west},
        ticks=none,
    ]

   \addplot3[
        opacity = 0.1,
        surf,
        z buffer = sort,
        shader=interp,
        fill=blue,
        samples = 20,
        variable = \u,
        variable y = \v,
        domain = 0:180,
        y domain = 0:360,
    ]
    ({10*cos(u)*sin(v)}, {10*sin(u)*sin(v)}, {10*cos(v)});


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

`mesh/interior colormap` allows to use a different `colormap`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        width=0.8\textwidth,
        axis equal,
        axis lines = center,
        x label style={at={(axis cs:0,2,0)},anchor=south},
        y label style={at={(axis cs:0,2,0)},anchor=west},
        z label style={at={(axis cs:-1,2,.1)},anchor=west},
        ticks=none,
    ]

   \addplot3[surf,
        opacity = 0.2,
        mesh/interior colormap=
           {blueblack}{color=(black) color=(blue)},
        mesh/interior colormap thresh=1,
        shader=interp,
        samples = 30,
        variable = \u,
        variable y = \v,
        domain = 0:360,
%        y domain = 0:360,
    ]
    ({10*cos(u)*sin(v)}, {10*sin(u)*sin(v)}, {10*cos(v)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However the result looks different in different pdf viewers:

**Acrobat Reader:**

[image]

**Evince:**

[image]

**Update**

You can also try the following options, if a single color, without shading is ok:

```
    draw opacity = 0.01,
    fill opacity = 0.1,
    shader=flat,
```

Comment: I'm not comfortable with this library. The compiling process is so slow and I couldn't draw even a solid sphere. Also, it throws out an error that the memory is exceeding the limit. Anyways, thanks for the answer.