# Draw a 3D curve using spherical coordinates

Tags: tikz-3dplot

I'm trying to plot some fibres of the function:
[image]

where points of the sphere are seen in the spherical coordinates system with `\theta` ranges over `[0,2pi[` and `\phi` over `[0,pi]`, and north and south poles are given the coordinates `N <-> (0,0)` and `S <-> (pi,pi)`. Here is my attempt to draw the fibre over `pi/4`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}   %no idea what this does%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [hide axis]
\addplot3[variable=t,mesh,domain=2*pi:5*pi/2] ({sin(deg(5*pi/(4*t)))*cos(deg(t))}, {sin(deg(5*pi/(4*t)))*sin(deg(t))}, {cos(deg(5*pi/(4*t)))});
\addplot3[variable=t,mesh,domain=5*pi/2:3*pi] ({sin(deg(5*pi/(4*(5*pi-t))))*cos(deg(t))}, {sin(deg(5*pi/(4*(5*pi-t))))*sin(deg(t))}, {cos(deg(5*pi/(4*(5*pi-t))))});
\addplot3[variable=t,mesh,domain=3*pi:7*pi/2] ({sin(deg(5*pi/(4*(t-pi))))*cos(deg(t))}, {sin(deg(5*pi/(4*(t-pi))))*sin(deg(t))}, {cos(deg(5*pi/(4*(t-pi))))});
\addplot3[variable=t,mesh,domain=7*pi/2:4*pi] ({sin(deg(5*pi/(4*(6*pi-t))))*cos(deg(t))}, {sin(deg(5*pi/(4*(6*pi-t))))*sin(deg(t))}, {cos(deg(5*pi/(4*(6*pi-t))))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I had to change the domain of `\theta` to avoid division by 0. The result is something like

[image]

However, I would like to additionally draw the sphere so that one can see that this curve lives on the sphere, but I seem to be unable to do it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I edited the question, but was unable to add pictures of how the result should look like because of lack of reputation :-|

Comment: You could draw a [sphere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261310/124842) like this.

Comment: just feel this figure is somehow interesting, mathematically!